# PHP web application can't connect mysql installed with Zend Server CE on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, php, mysql, zend

I'm setting up development environment on Mac OSX.

However the PHP web application can't connect the mysql server installed with Zend Server CE.

The error information is below,

```
[Type] dbnot_connect
[2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61
```

Mysql database can be accessed via phpAdmin installed with Zend Server CE as well.

The same code works well on Windows or Linux in Zend Server CE.

Comment: Is the phpMyAdmin installed on the server or on your development environment? It could be an issue with your `bind` not allowing outside of `localhost` access. If this is not the case then check your connection string to make sure that it's coded properly.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is installed my Mac as well. It can access mysql server(installed on Mac). 
And the code is checked out from source control, it works well to linux/windows to access the mysql installed with Zend Server on linux/windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting on the command line to mysql - perhaps you need to specify a different port?  Also there is the issue of the file /var/mysql/mysql.sock in Lion - you have to link this file.  Here's a list of instructions: http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/